# Make function recursive

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

I am trying to convert my function below to a recursive one but I keep getting an error when I try it.

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'`

```
def turtle_spiral(forward):

    minus = 8

    t = turtle.Turtle()

    t.pendown()

    t.shape("turtle")
    #while forward > 10:

    randm = random.randrange(5)
    colours = ["blue", "orange", "yellow", "green",   "purple","black","red","pink"]

    t.goto(-100,0)

    if forward <= 10:
        return False

    else:
        t.color(colours[randm])
        #t.speed(10)
        t.fd(turtle_spiral(forward*minus))
        #t.circle(forward, 360)
        t.right(90)
        #forward -= minus


turtle_spiral(100)

wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nothing in this code uses the `*` operator.

Comment: The code you've shown is not at all recursive, so we can't figure out what recursive problems you're having since there's no recursion to look at. We can't even run the code as it's been posted, since there are indentation errors. Please post the code that you're actually having problems with, and the full traceback of the exception.

Comment: Sorry let me edit it quickly

Comment: A common error in recursive programming is to forget to return a value in all cases, especially the return value from the recursive call itself. Without a specific return value, python returns `None` and you get the error. Since we don't have your real code yet... this is just a guess!

Comment: I just added my attempted code , my apologies again

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at modifying your code to do what I *think* you want to do:

```
import turtle
import random

def turtle_spiral(forward):

    minus = 8
    randm = random.randrange(5)
    colours = ["blue", "orange", "yellow", "green",   "purple","black","red","pink"]

    if forward <= 10:
        return 0
    else:
        t.color(colours[randm])
        t.right(90)
        t.fd(forward)
        return turtle_spiral(forward-minus)

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.pendown()

t.shape("turtle")
turtle_spiral(100)
```

The key to recursion is defining the end point(s) of your recursion. In your case, it is when the turtle is being asked to go forward a distance of less than 10. At the end point the recursive function should not call itself and just return.

In other cases we want the function to call itself at some point with an argument that gets it somewhat closer towards the end-point. In your case this argument is `forward-minus` and this value will get closer and closer to the end condition the more `turtle_spiral` calls itself recursively.

Comment: No problem! As you get more practised your code gets less messy :)

Answer (score 0):

Although John Sharp nicely analyzed your code to come up with what you wanted your turtle to do, I read between the lines, aka your commented out code, to come up with what you really wish your turtle could do:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import choice, randrange

LENGTH = 200
LIMIT = 10
DELTA = 16

colors = ["blue", "orange", "cyan", "green", "purple", "black", "red", "magenta"]

def turtle_spiral(turtle, length, delta, limit):

    if length < limit:
        return

    extent = 360 / delta

    for radius in range(delta):
        turtle.circle(length - radius, extent=extent)
        if randrange(delta) == 0:
            turtle.color(choice(colors))

    turtle_spiral(turtle, length - delta, delta, limit)

yertle = Turtle(shape="turtle", visible=False)

yertle.speed("fastest")

yertle.penup()
yertle.sety(-LENGTH)
yertle.pendown()

yertle.showturtle()

turtle_spiral(yertle, LENGTH, DELTA, LIMIT)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

I also threw in some style changes -- see if they make sense to you.  For example: there's no need for `turtle_spiral()` to return a value, nothing's looking at the result; get your global definitions, like the `colors` array, out of the running code; pass the turtle and other information into `turtle_spiral()` as arguments -- with event timers you could then have more than one of these running at a time; keep your turtle invisible until you get it to the starting point then reveal it.

[image]